# How do I find the best matching revision in a version control system?

Tags: svn, version-control, diff

I downloaded a single file from an subversion repository (subversion) long time ago. So this is *not* a checkout from that repository. I altered this file, but I do not remember the revision when I downloaded this file.

The project evolved and now I want to merge these to files (after two years). This file is a *huge* script.

So my basic attempt is to find the best matching revision from repository in order to see what I've altered and then finally merge these two files. For that purpose I would checkout every revision from which I am thinking it could be this revision until now, make a diff, and count lines. I think, the smallest diff will give me the best matching revision.

Any other Idea?

Comment: When I've read half of your question I had thought about exactly the same way of searching

Comment: But it is definitve not correct, I employed a little script, but the numbers of affected lines has local minima over time. And even the global minium didn't matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an interesting question, but at the end, you have to merge with the latest revision of the file (if it currently exists, if not, you have another problem). So I don't think that the *best matching* revision gives you a better start point than the current revision.

So try to diff with the current revision, and if you don't understand how it evolved, read (with a good tool, best graphically) how the file has changed to understand where which lines of code came from.

Comment: It sort of depends on the VCS ... why did I keep using SVN so long? :( But the "best matching" *might* be useful to see what else was about at said point time, not just trying to figure out how to merge it in.

Comment: Yes I already started but got lost within the changes since there are many cosmetic changes which disturb to focus on the real changes. (which good tools I should have a look at for subversion?) If I start with that revision I will find out what changes _I've_ made, and which of the I can consider as obsolete by now.

Comment: I gave up, since I found changes from other team members too (which I wasn't aware), so I have to merge anyway. You were right.